# A question about Unicode character (U+0096)(inputenc)

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I am using a LaTeX document which can be compiled without any problems. However, after copying some text into the document, I have got a large number of errors that say:

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+0096)(inputenc) not set
>   up for use with LaTeX. \end{tabular}

I don't know what could be wrong with that copied text. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably an encoding issue for en-dash characters, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52967769/5763564. The en-dash is a dash character – that is a bit wider than - (a hyphen character as found on most keyboards). So you could check the text that you copied if there are any dash characters and replace them with hyphens, or double hyphens `--` if you actually want a dash.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/24500162 (a link similar to Marijn's link above). New versions of LaTeX assume your document is UTF-8 encoded if you don't explicitly state a different encoding with `inputenc`. Since `0096` is the code point of the en-dash in a different encoding, this suggests that your document might have been written in a different encoding. If only the en-dash is causing trouble (not only error-wise, check the output carefully as well), it may be enough to find and replace all en-dashes in your document. (`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0096}{XXX here I am XXX}` can help.)

Comment: If there are more characters that don't quite work, you need to figure out which encoding your document uses (the link I read suggests WIN-1252). You can then either find the appropriate `inputenc` setting (if WIN-1252 is right that would be `\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}`) or re-encode your document in UTF-8 (this is generally the best solution nowadays; make sure to retain a copy of the old file in case something goes wrong during re-encoding).